# Signals/slots in PyQT5 are not working since array is not visible for function

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyqt5

I have 3 files: Gui.py, IPG_weld.py, Reading.py

Gui.py is:

```
  import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
    from PyQt5 import QtGui
    from Ipg_weld import Ui_IPG_weld


    class Test(Ui_IPG_weld):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self.widget)
        ...
        self.widget.show()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ipg_Weld.py is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'D:\IPG_Weld\ipg_weld.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Reading import reading

class Ui_IPG_weld(object):
    def setupUi(self, IPG_weld):
        IPG_weld.setObjectName("IPG_weld")
        IPG_weld.resize(1107, 641)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(IPG_weld)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.Savebutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.Savebutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(930, 520, 131, 51))
        self.Savebutton.setObjectName("Savebutton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 20, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 55, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 55, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 55, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 90, 55, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 130, 55, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 170, 55, 16))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 210, 55, 16))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 250, 55, 16))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 290, 55, 16))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 330, 55, 16))
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 370, 55, 16))
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 410, 55, 16))
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 450, 55, 16))
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 490, 55, 16))
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.Read_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.Read_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 520, 131, 51))
        self.Read_Button.setObjectName("Read_Button")
        first_text=self.Read_Button.Clicked.Connect(reading())
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 70, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 110, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 150, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_3")
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 80, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.plainTextEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 120, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_5")
        self.plainTextEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 160, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_6.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_6")
        self.plainTextEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 200, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_7.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_7")
        self.plainTextEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 240, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_8.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_8")
        self.plainTextEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 280, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_9.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_9")
        self.plainTextEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 320, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_10.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_10")
        self.plainTextEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 360, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_11.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_11")
        self.plainTextEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 400, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_12.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_12")
        self.plainTextEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 440, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_13.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_13")
        self.plainTextEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 480, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_14.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_14")
        self.plainTextEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 70, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_15.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_15.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_15")
        self.plainTextEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_16.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_16.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_16")
        self.plainTextEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_17.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_17.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_17")
        self.plainTextEdit_18 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 80, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_18.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_18.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_18")
        self.plainTextEdit_19 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 120, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_19.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_19.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_19")
        self.plainTextEdit_20 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 160, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_20.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_20.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_20")
        self.plainTextEdit_21 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 200, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_21.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_21.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_21")
        self.plainTextEdit_22 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 240, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_22.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_22.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_22")
        self.plainTextEdit_23 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 280, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_23.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_23.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_23")
        self.plainTextEdit_24 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 320, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_24.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_24.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_24")
        self.plainTextEdit_25 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_25.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 360, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_25.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_25.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_25")
        self.plainTextEdit_26 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_26.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 400, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_26.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_26.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_26")
        self.plainTextEdit_27 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_27.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 440, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_27.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_27.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_27")
        self.plainTextEdit_28 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_28.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 480, 41, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_28.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit_28.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_28")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 50, 55, 16))
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 50, 55, 16))
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        IPG_weld.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(IPG_weld)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1107, 26))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        IPG_weld.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(IPG_weld)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        IPG_weld.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(IPG_weld)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        IPG_weld.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(IPG_weld)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(IPG_weld)

    def retranslateUi(self, IPG_weld):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        IPG_weld.setWindowTitle(_translate("IPG_weld", "IPG_weld"))
        self.Savebutton.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Сохранить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Inputs"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Outputs"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Active"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Ready"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Error"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 0"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 1"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 2"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 3"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 4"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 5"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 6"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 7"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Bit 8"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Strobe"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Start"))
        self.Read_Button.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Считать значения"))
        #self.plainTextEdit_18.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "1"))
        self.plainTextEdit_18.setPlainText(first_edit[1])
        self.plainTextEdit_19.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "2"))
        self.plainTextEdit_20.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "3"))
        self.plainTextEdit_21.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "4"))
        self.plainTextEdit_22.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "5"))
        self.plainTextEdit_23.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "6"))
        self.plainTextEdit_24.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "7"))
        self.plainTextEdit_25.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "8"))
        self.plainTextEdit_26.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "9"))
        self.plainTextEdit_27.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "10"))
        self.plainTextEdit_28.setPlainText(_translate("IPG_weld", "11"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Текущее "))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Новое"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Текущее "))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("IPG_weld", "Новое"))
```

And Reading.py is:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import re
def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        stripped=[row.strip() for row in f]
        setup_weld_num = [re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',i).group(1) for i in stripped if re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',i)]
        print(setup_weld_num)

reading()
```

So what I'm currenlty trying to do is to connect two buttons,that was created in IPG_weld.py (Read_Button and Save_Button) to my events:
When Read_Button clicked , reading() in reading.py should be executed where array Setup_weld_num will be filled, and 
  PlainTextEdit_18  to  PlainTextEdit_28 received elements from setup_weld_num array. In another words, I want to read from file:

```
&ACCESS RVP1
&REL 3
&PARAM DISKPATH = KRC:\R1\Program\new
DEF SETUP_WELD()
;call LASER_EN();

$out[27]=false;  START=OFF
$out[26]=false;  STROBE=OFF
$out[25]=false;  SELECT 8=OFF
$out[24]=false;  SELECT 7 =OFF
$out[23]=false;  SELECT 6 =OFF
$out[22]=false;  SELECT 5 =OFF
$out[21]=false;  SELECT 4 =OFF
$out[20]=false;  SELECT 3 =OFF
$out[19]=false;  SELECT 2 =OFF
$out[18]=false;  SELECT 1 =OFF
$out[17]=false;  SELECT 0 =OFF
$out[28]=true;  ENABLE=ON

END
```

And translate number of outputs to Plain_TextEdit_18 - plainTextEdit_25, so the user will able to see them in text box in Gui.

How to do it properly?

UPD: As you can See I added:

```
first_text=self.Read_Button.Clicked.Connect(reading())
```

and tried to transfer the 1st element of ***first_edit*** array into ***PlainTextEdit_18***:

```
self.plainTextEdit_18.setPlainText(first_edit[1])
```

But its not working, because array ***first_edit*** is not visible for retranslate_UI function.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments on a top of `Ipg_weld.py` states, it's useless to add any code to this file since it will be rewritten by Qt UI compiler. Consider adding a click handler function to your class `Test` in `Gui.py`. For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from Ipg_weld import Ui_IPG_weld
import Reading


class Test(Ui_IPG_weld):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self.widget)
        # ...
        self.widget.show()

    def read_file(self):
        file_values = Reading.reading()
        print("Got values:", file_values)
        # change this accordingly
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(file_values[0])
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(file_values[1])
        # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   main = Test()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then you have handler function, connect button signal to it. Note that `QPushButton` has signal [clicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#signals) (case matters) and signals has method `connect` ([more about signals and slots in pyqt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html)).

In your example line `first_text=self.Read_Button.Clicked.Connect(reading())` actually **calls** `reading` (note the parentheses), but while connecting signal and slot you must provide a callable to `connect` method (consider it like you specifying a name of function rather than calling it).

Summing that up, add connection to your `__init__` of class **Test**:

```
class Test(Ui_IPG_weld):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self.widget)
        # ...
        # connecting button. Note that you should not call 
        # self.read_file here.
        self.Read_Button.clicked.connect(self.read_file)
        self.widget.show()
```

Now you should see `file_values` printing while clicking the button.

Comment: Thank you kindly,sir,that helped !